# Macro to Search, find, copy, paste a word and merge cells

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to make a macro that can:

1. search for the word "Yes" in all rows in column E, copy and paste it to the corresponded row in column B (the same row)
2. Merge the cell in column B with the cell in column C

For example:
The macro is searchig for the word "Yes" in column E, the word "Yes" is found in E5, copy and paste "Yes" to B5, merge B5 and C5 and confirm the merging (excell always displays a pop un window asking to manually click on the button to confirm the merging), continue with next search.

Comment: You mean merge the cells as in the button merge cells or do you mean append the Yes with what is in C5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It will not ask anything when merging cells and the area will take the left cell value (B = Yes). If you need the value in C, or a concatenation between the two cells, you must tell us that:

```
Sub testMergeYesWord()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
 lastR = sh.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    
 For i = 2 To lastR
    If UCase(sh.Range("E" & i).Value) = "YES" Then
        sh.Range("B" & i).Value = sh.Range("E" & i).Value
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'to avoid the message asking what value to be allocate to the merged area
         sh.Range("B" & i & ":C" & i).merge
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
 Next i
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: @nikolaikolev: Didn't you find some time to test the above code?

Comment: I did mate but for some reason it does not work if it goes along with other macros in same sub. But if it is in an separate alone sub as your code is it work like a charm. thanx mate.

Comment: @nikolaikolev: You may call the above `Sub` at the end of your 'other macro'...

Comment: i did it and it work just fine. thank you very much